# How to convert a Vec to a ndarray

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I'm starting to learn rust, so let me know if there is a more proper way I should be approaching this problem, but I'm looking for similar performance of numpy from python when doing element wise operations on vectors. It looks like the ndarray crate is a good fit, but I'm having a hard time turning a Vec into a ndarray.
Starting with:

```
let mut A:Vec<f32> = vec![];
```

How would I do something like:

```
let B = array!(A);
```

after filling in the vector?

I didn't see a way to cast the vector to an ndarray like I would in python with lists. Do I really have to just use a for loop and set each index individually to an empty ndarray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [from_vec](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.from_vec) to create an `ndarray` from a vector or [from_shape_vec](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.from_shape_vec) to create a vector of a custom dimension.

```rust
// You can use from_vec
let one_dim_vector = Array::from_vec(vec![1, 2, 3, 4]);
println!("Vector created from_vec:\n{:#?}", one_dim_vector);
```

Or you can create it from an iterable:

```rust
let one_dim_vector_from_iterable = Array::from_iter(1..5);
println!(
    "Vector created from_iter:\n{:#?}",
    one_dim_vector_from_iterable
);
```

You can also create it for a custom dimension passing a tuple of (rows, columns):

```rust
let vector_of_custom_dimension = Array::from_shape_vec((3, 2), vec![1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.]);
match vector_of_custom_dimension {
    Ok(vector) => println!("Vector created from_shape_vec:\n{:#?}", vector),
    Err(error) => println!("Error: {:#?}", error),
}
```

This will output:

```rust
Vector created from_vec: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Vector created from_iter: [1, 2, 3, 4]
Vector created from_shape_vec: 
[[1.0, 2.0],
 [3.0, 4.0]],
```

Comment: It would be nice if the example didn't have the same width and height, since it doesn't let readers intuit which dimension/axis is which. Not even the library docs disambiguate how to use this.

Comment: Added. But I guess its an unsaid rule that dimension of a matrix, vector, table, dataframe, n-dimensional array or anything that has rows and columns is always written as (Row * Columns)

Answer (score 2):

[`ArrayBase` implements `From<Vec>`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.6/src/ndarray/arraytraits.rs.html#164-180), so you can just use that:

```rust
let B = ndarray::Array1::from(A);
```